# IOS Stop run script from app store build

Tags: ios, xcode

Iv recently added a run script to my project which i only want to be executed if the archive build configuration is not set to "App Store", I have been searching for ages and I have come across "if [ $CONFIGURATION = "App Store" ]; then" approach multiple times but no matter what i compare the $configuration to (i.e "Release" or "Debug", it always runs the script. Anyone have any ideas why this isn't working or any other ways to preventing a script from running on an app store build?

Thanks,
Liam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `if[$CONFIGURATION = "App Store"]`, then replace the equal sign with two equal signs: `if[$CONFIGURATION == "App Store"]`. That makes a lot of difference in programming world :)

You might have to add quotation marks on the $CONFIGURATION part, like `if["$CONFIGURATION" == "App Store"]`, but I'm not sure. Try both and tell us your results ;)

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I had tried the == but that didn't work before, but i added the == and quotes around $configuration and curly braces and it worked perfect. If anyone else gets stuck on this if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" == "App Store" ]; then fixed mine.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to know I helped :)